# STM32F4 HW_CRYPTO lower performance

Tags: cryptography, stm32, freertos, polarssl

I use FreeRTOS, LWiP, PolarSSL with STM32F417, 1MB external RAM.

When I use code with `USE_STM32F4XX_HW_CRYPTO` defined it works but the performance are lower or same like without HW acceleration. Why?

Comment: That's a very specific question, I hope you can find an expert. Note that using HW crypto may have other advantages than performance wrt side channel analysis and secure key storage. CPU's are pretty darn fast nowadays, even in embedded systems.

Comment: Do you call the good API to use hw crypto?